# Ошибка 404 при подставлении метки yclid

Tags: php, .htaccess

Всем доброго дня. При автоматической подстановке метки yclid Яндексом, сервер возвращает страницу 404. Я знаю, что нужно в .htaccess нужно настроить произвольные параметры URL, но как это сделать не знаю, в силу отсутствия знаний в языке php. В интернете информации не нашел. Подскажите нужные строчки кода для решения проблемы. Всем мира и добра!

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено. Очень странно, что никто не отвечает на аналогичные вопросы на форумах. Проблема популярная и вот решение для нее. В файле .htaccess добавьте строки:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([a-z-/]*)\?yclid= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301,QSD,L]
```

Comment: Чтобы на такие вопросы отвечали, нужно в вопросах предоставлять [mcve] демонстрирующий проблему